# How to add clickable FlatList item and navigate to Detail component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a FlatList showing on main screen and on click of a FlatList item I want to navigate to the Detail component and pass related data to detail component.As I am new to react native I am struggling hard to implement this functionality though I have implemented FlatList on main screen.FlatList has been implemented under `list.js` component from this component I want to navigate to `details.js` component.

Below is my code:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {StatusBar, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import List from './components/list';
import Detail from './components/details';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {

return (
  
  <NavigationContainer>
  <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" backgroundColor="#8E24AA"/>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen 
    name="Home" 
    component={List}
    options={{ 
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#AB47BC',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff' }} />

    <Stack.Screen 
    name="Detail" 
    component={Detail}
    options={{ 
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#AB47BC',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff' }} />  
  </Stack.Navigator>
 </NavigationContainer>   

  ) 
}

export default App;
```

**list.js**

```
import React, {useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import {View,Text,StyleSheet,ActivityIndicator,FlatList} from 'react-native';

const List = () => {

 const[post,setPost] = useState([]);
 const[isLoading,setLoading] = useState(true);

 useEffect(() => {
    
    const url = 'http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=simpsons+characters&format=json';
    fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())
    .then((resp) => {
        setPost(resp.RelatedTopics);
        setLoading(false);
    }).catch((err) => alert(err));
 },[]);

 const FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
  return (
   <View
    style={{  
      height: 0.7,
      width: "100%",
      backgroundColor: "#adadad"
     }}
   />
  );
}

    return(
 
       <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center'}}>

        { isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator color="#8E24AA" size="large"/> : <FlatList 
            data = {post} 
            keyExtractor = {(item) => item.FirstURL} 
            renderItem = {({item}) => <Text style={styles.my}>{item.Text}</Text>} 
            ItemSeparatorComponent = { FlatListItemSeparator }/>  }
      
      </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  my:{
     marginBottom: 15,
     marginTop: 15,
     marginLeft: 15
   }
});

export default List;
```

**details.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,Text} from 'react-native';

const Detail = () => {

    return(
      <View>
          <Text>Hello there</Text>
      </View>
    );
};

export default Detail;
```

Someone let me know how can I implement desired functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a TouchableOpacity, wrapping your Text component in renderItem. Add the function to onPress and then get the navigation prop and navigate to the Detail screen, passing the item. You can access these data through the route prop in the Detail screen.

```
    const handlePress = (item) => {
       navigation.navigate('Detail', item);
    }

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
      handlePress(item);
    }>
      <Text style={styles.my}>{item.Text}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>


In Detail, add the following code.

    const Detail = ({navigation, route}) => {
      const {Text} = route.params
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>{Text}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    };
```

Comment: HOw can i get that text value in Details component.

Comment: Its showing error `Cannot find variable: navigation`.

Comment: @Digvijay Passing text value updated in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67799772/11106406

Comment: @Digvijay update to const List = ({navigation}) => {

Comment: Yeah its navigationg now let me try with passing data to details component.

Comment: How can I add Text passed in detail component in its header title.

Answer (score 1):

Each screen defined in Navigator receives a prop called `navigation` which has various methods to link to other screens.

1. update the `List` component definition to use the prop `navigation`

```
const List = ({navigation}) => {
...
```

2. use navigation.navigate to go to the Detail screen:

```
 //Add an onPress event handler 
 renderItem={({item}) => (
   <Text onPress={navigateToDetails} style={styles.my}>
    {item.Text}
   </Text>
 )}
```

Use `navigation.navigate` with Screen name defined in `Stack.Navigator`( ie `Detail`) to navigate to the Detail screen.

```
const navigateToDetails = () => {
  navigation.navigate('Detail');
};
```

3. For passing params to Detail screen, put them in an object as a second parameter to the navigation.navigate function: `navigation.navigate('RouteName', { /* params go here */ })`

updating the onPress Function to pass item

```
  renderItem={({item}) => (
    <Text onPress={() => navigateToDetails(item)} style={styles.my}>
      {item.Text}
    </Text>
  )}

 // Update function definition to

  const navigateToDetails = item => {
    navigation.navigate('Detail', item);
  };
```

4. To access the params in `Detail` screen, Read the params in your screen component: `route.params`

```
const Detail = ({navigation, route}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hello there {route.params.Text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

for more details on navigation: [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating#navigating-to-a-new-screen)

Answer (score 1):

firstly you need to get `navigation prop` on the list component

```
const List = ({navigation}) => { //<====
```

then you can use `navigation` and pass the data like this

```
 renderItem = {({item}) => <Text onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("Detail",{item})} style={styles.my}>{item.Text}</Text>}
```

and get your data on `Detail` screen like this

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,Text} from 'react-native';

const Detail = ({route}) => {
    const {item}=route.params

    console.log("data is =>",item)
    return(
      <View>
          <Text>Hello there</Text>
      </View>
    );
};

export default Detail;
```